# Conductors interacting with a positive plate, What happens inside the conductor itself

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

A circular conductor is placed next to a positively charged plate in oil with suspended rayon fibers. The rayon fibers align with the geometry of the electric field. The field looks like so: [image]

What conclusions can be drawn from this demonstration for the electric field inside the conductor?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we can tell that the E-field entering the conductor is always perpendicular to the surface of the conductor. Also since we know from Gauss Law that the perpendicular components of the field must obey:
$$D_a=D_c \rightarrow E_a \epsilon_a=E_c \epsilon_c$$

Moreover since for a perfect conductor $ \epsilon_c $ approaches $\infty$, we can say that the Electric field in a perfect conductor must be 0.